# How do I bind the BackColor (or other properties) of a control to a string value stored in the DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, properties

So I have a database with color values stored in ARBG format as INTEGERS. What I want to do is bind the backcolor of a control to the database so that the color matches the control background according to the record selected. (i.e Each record has a color and when the form changes the record display on the bindingsource then the controls background changes to match the color INT in the database for that record).

I have this so far (which does not work):

```
pictureBox1.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", BindingSource1, "ColorINT");
```

The problem is that the database stores the color as an INTEGER and the databind expects a color but I am unable to call the Color.FromArgb function to change the binding back to a color. How can I do this?

Comment: What language and tools/frameworks are you using? Can you add tags for those so that people familiar with them might find your question?

Comment: You can subscribe to the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.format) and [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding.parse) events of the Binding before adding it to a Control's DataBindings. This allows to convert the data format back and forth. Then it depends on what the integer represents, i.e., if it's compatible with the `Color.FromArgb([int])` method. But of course, when the events are raised, you can use your own conversion method.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi Updated my original post with the answer. Not quite sure what is going on there but it works!

Comment: @chepox Please do not add the answer to the question. Post answers as Answer by click on "Post Your Answer" button. You can also ask Jimi to see if he may want to extend his comment and post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jimi for the reply I was finally able to figure it out. Posting for someone who might have a similar question:

```
private void IntegerToColor(object sender, ConvertEventArgs cevent)
    {
        if (cevent.DesiredType != typeof(Color)) return;
        cevent.Value = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(cevent.Value));
    }
```

// then on form load

```
Binding PicColorBind = new Binding("BackColor", BindingSource1, "ColorINT");
        PicColorBind.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(IntegerToColor);
        picColor.DataBindings.Add(PicColorBind);
```